# Liquibase: capture stored procedures, functions and triggers

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

How to capture the stored procedures, functions of a schema in SQL Server using liquibase?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Using the free version of liquibase you cant catch stored procedures, functions, and triggers. This functional is allowed only for commercial version according to the [official documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html)

With a commercial version of liquibase, you could use the `generateChangeLog` command to generate the changelog file that contains whole information about the given schema in xml format.

```
liquibase
--changeLogFile=dbchangelog.xml
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
--classpath=ojdbc14.jar
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP OR HOSTNAME>:<PORT>:<SERVICE NAME OR SID>"
--defaulSchemaName=<shemaName>
--username=<USERNAME>
--password=<PASSWORD>
generateChangeLog
```

The liquibase distribution does not contain the database driver so you shell download it by your own hand and put it to the classpath. Also you could set explicitly the schema name (it's not required for oracle cause liquibase will use the schema that associated with a given user).

If you want to generate plain SQL you should use the `updateSQL` command

```
liquibase
--changeLogFile=dbchangelog.xml
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
--classpath=ojdbc14.jar
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP OR HOSTNAME>:<PORT>:<SERVICE NAME OR SID>"
--username=<USERNAME>
--password=<PASSWORD>
updateSQL
```

Here you should use the dbchangelog.xml file that was generated earlier with `generateChangeLog` command. You should set the proper database URL and credentials because liquibase will generate the database-specific SQL.